# Firebase design, only unique nodes based on token

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my idea was initially to write purchasetoken ids as a node, but firebase nodes don't allow special characters in a node name.

This is an example purchasetoken:
token_value = 'gclnkgdeflokebifhnonbipf.AO-J1Oz7BhpVUYd_l67lFY3WRkKkJ-wasXh7i3G-DgS6yXfbew5-qnP5k3xTfKuXQlKQzkQzLLUqf_yxFnmZKhBwrtX-lZzeGLcm56lLX32_bwwOeO9aJyI'

Actually I hoped that I can use this as a node to avoid users to try to validate the same token multiple times since in my dbrules, nodes have to be unique and my cloud function trigger listens to new posts on this path.

What could I do instead to achieve the same result?

The posted purchasetoken nodes should be unique and in the same time bound to the actual purchase token value, so that my trigger function doesn't get called for the same tokens multiple times.

I am thinking of a way to encrypt the purchase token with a function that removes the characters that the firebase doesn't allow as a node-name. But if there are better solutions, I'd be glad to hear them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the token contains character that are not allowed in the keys of the Firebase Realtime Database, you will need to encode the token.

There are two common ways to do this:

- A lossless encoding/decoding, such as [URL-encoding/percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) which replaces disallowed characters with a percent-prefixed hex value. For example, a `/` in the token would be encoded as `%2F`. The advantage of this type of encoding is that you can decode the original token out of the key when needed.
- A lossy encoding/decoding, for example by dropping any disallowed character from the token and then using the result as the key. This is typically much simpler to implement, and you don't need a decoder. But of course it also means you can't get the token back from the key, and (more importantly) you *might* have two tokens map to the same key, so you'd need to handle these situations.

Neither of these is pertinently better than the other. It all depends on your use-cases, and personal preferences.